# Network reachability check in WatchKit

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, nsurlsession, apple-watch

As SystemConfiguration framework is not supported for watchKit OS, has anyone worked on or know of an alternate method to do network reachability check in a Watch App?

Please excuse if this is a stupid question as I'm new to this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you do have urlsession available, why cant you just hit a URL and check if you get response or error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check internet connection availability there are two ways.

1) Just call a simple `NSURLSession`(`Alamofire` if you prefer) and it will return you an error with no internet. Using this you can handle your stuff. At a moment there are no such observers to help you with when connection is back.

2) Using `WatchConnectivity` framework you can send message to iOS and get the status of internet.

Best way I would suggest is the first one but still depends on your usage.

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing for watchOS4 
Check this video https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/fall2017/203/
and use URLSession and set waitForConnectivity = true